# MCP3008 vs ADS1015 which one among these two would be best for heart beat monitor?

Tags: iot

I want a ADC convertor for heartrate monitor.
Which on will be the best.
I am confused between 10 bit and 12 bit resolutin in ADC.
Any suggestions would be really helpfull.

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-heartbeat-pulse-measuring/
http://udayankumar.com/2016/05/17/heart-beat-raspberry/

Comment: Read the 'features' section from the respective datasheets for a quick comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 bit would give the range of 0-1023 as output

12 bit would give the range of 0-4095 as output

This means getting the second converter (12 bit) would give you four times the accuracy. Beyond that I don't really have any more info to add!